# Why are the openapi-generator generated files ignored?

Tags: java, rest, resteasy, openapi-generator

For my project, I want to generate my restapi based on an openapi spec. The generated classes are annotated with @Path and @Get from the javax library.

Unfortunately the generated class is not 'picked up' by the CDI. When I look at the CDI beans, it just isn't there.

This is a 'working' example of this problem. Clone the repo, mvn clean verify and the designated test will fail (404 instead of 200): https://github.com/rmvanderspek/generate-api

Comment: From quickly looking at the `pom.xml`, it seems the classes are generated into `src/gen/java`, but are they even compiled? I'd first try configuring `src/gen/java` as a source path for Maven, to get them compiled.

Comment: Yes, thanks, your comment led to a better understanding of the problem. Thus to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, the problem is due to the openapi-plugin configuration. By default, the jaxrs-resteasy opeapi-generator put the generated files in `targe/generated-classes/openapi/**src/gen/java**`. The implementation class is the only exception, which does get put in `src/main/java`.

To fix this issue, one needs to add another plugin that adds this folder to the application sources:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>add-source</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <sources>src/gen/java</sources>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```